# javascript to run client's oulook using ActiveXObject with attachment from the Downloads folder on the local system

Tags: javascript, outlook, activexobject

I need help with this problem.
I use the code below to run the client's outlook new email with attachment,
it is was working perfectly when I was using the exact path of the file like 
add. `("C:/USERS/MY USER NAME/Downloads/".fileName)`.
But when I changed it to `Add("%userprofile%/Downloads/"+fileName)` to access the current user logged in,
it didn't work with no errors, it seems can't find the file.
Is there something wrong?? Or different way to do that??

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var theApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
      var objNS = theApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
      var theMailItem = theApp.CreateItem(0); 
      theMailItem.Attachments.Add("%userprofile%/Downloads/"+FileName);
      theMailItem.display();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment. The method doesn't accept environment variables, you must specify the fully-qualified file path.

To get a fully-qualified file path you can use the following code:

```
var ObjShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var wShell   = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var path     = wShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%userprofile%\\Downloads\\");
```

So then you will be able to attach a file:

```
theMailItem.Attachments.Add(path+FileName);
```

Comment: thank you so much, this is working perfectly..... I appreciate it.